# Service Cloud Macros - Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning, service-cloud-console, macros

With Macros in Service Cloud Console for Lightning, how is one able to insert pre-defined text into an email send or reply? Within the Macro Builder I believe I can perform most tasks, but the body of the email is not made available. As can be seen in the image below, I would love my action to include text that is inserted into the email reply, but it only gives me options to update settings (subject, to/from, send, etc).

[image]

Working through the trailhead it gives this type of task as a common use-case, so I am not sure if it is lightning-specific or if I am just missing steps.

Answer (score 0):

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003VWCQA2

It's still an "idea" - feature request....